# How to disable or remove an input search filter in ag-grid-react?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am using [ag-grid-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-react)

In one specific column I have an icon that copies the info of the row, so the filter input should not be there. I want to disable it or remove it.

I think it is related with the `columnsDef` property of the grid component.

I tried adding `getQuickFilterText: () => ''` in my column section, but there is no change in the input. Is there another option I can try?

Answer (score 0):

The `AgGridReact` takes a prop called `columnDefs` that is an array of objects that represent each column, right?

In order to disable/remove the filter input of a specific column, inside the object that represent that specific column, add:

```
   filter: () => ‘’
```

Hope it helps others with same issue.

Comment: When I copy-pasted this code, the error I am getting is Invalid character. ‘’ is invalid

Comment: BTW I am using angular

Comment: Hello, maybe the quote character is different. Try deleting and typing the quotes from your keyboard (do not copy-paste). You can also try double quotes.

Comment: I have tried it. I am getting the error `Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string | boolean | (new () => IFilterComp)'.`

Comment: Ok. This is a different error (so the previous one maybe is solved). This new one looks like a TS error. Are you using typescript? I recommend you to create a new question in Stackoverflow with the tools to reproduce your particular case. If you then comment here with the question link I will take a look. Regards.